# How do I create a class with reference member and vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, entity-component-system

I am fairly new to C++ and am working on a personal project. I want to create a `vector<Entity*> entitities` in C++ where each `Entity` object is unique. I have a class inside header `Entity.h` that I want to create. Now Entity takes two member variables:

1. `Rectangle rect` - an Object of type `Rectangle` that has four float variables as member variables (x1, y1, x2, y2) which are the coordinates of two opposite corners of a rectangle
2. `vector<Component*>` - a number of different components of Base class type `Component` with some Derived classes. The code for `Class Component` looks like so:

```
/*************************** BASE CLASS **************************/
class Component
{
public:
    virtual ~Component() = default;
    virtual Component* Clone() = 0;
};

/*************************** DERIVED CLASS 1 **************************/
class BasicComponent: public Component
{
private:
    int B= 0;
public:
    BasicComponent* Clone() override {
        return new BasicComponent(B);
    }

    BasicComponent(const int& mB) :B(mB){}
    BasicComponent() :B(0) {}

};

/*************************** DERIVED CLASS 2 **************************/
class AdvancedComponent: public Component
{
private:
    float A = 0.f;
    int iA = 0;
public:
    AdvancedComponent* Clone() override {
        return new AdvancedComponent(A, iA);
    }

    AdvancedComponent(const float& mA, const int& miA) :A(mA),iA(miA) {}
    AdvancedComponent() :A(0.f),iA(0) {}

};
```

Since I want each `Entity` in the vector of entities to be unique, that is, have it's own rectangle and components, how should I create the class ?

My question here is, what should the `class Entity` look like ? Should I create separate CopyConstructor, Assignment Constructor and Destructor for this class ? Also if I want to implement copying one Entity into another (deep copying), is it necessary to have all 3 (Copy, Assignment and Destructor) ?

Comment: You’ve given the members of `Entity`, right?  What’s stopping you from writing the class?

Comment: Why is `vector<Entity*>` relevant? Is it not enough to say that each `Entity` must have its own copy of the `Rectangle` and `Component`s from which it was constructed?

Comment: @DavisHerring. I already did it but I'm just not sure of my solution (since I'm very new to C++ and normally code on C#. The concept of pointers / addresses confuses me as on C# it's all very easy)

Comment: @RahulPillai: C# *has* pointers; it just doesn’t have the syntax.

Comment: @JaMiT. Not sure what you meant. Is it wrong to use ```vector<Entity*>``` instead of ```vector<Entity>``` ? . I was just not sure about what was more efficient and I just wanted to not lose my entities from out of the heap and so did not want them to be created on the stack.

Comment: @RahulPillai *"Is it wrong to use `vector<Entity*>` instead of `vector<Entity>` ?"* -- That's not what I am getting at. You are asking about your code; I am talking about your question. Simpler questions have fewer distractions, hence are more likely to get answered without getting lost on a tangent. What is lost if you drop all mention of vectors **from your question** and just state that each `Entity` must have its own `Rectangle` and `Component`s? (Emphasizing the vector over the requirement makes it seem like maybe objects not in the vector must share rectangles and components.)

Comment: @JaMiT. I see your point now. Let me make it a little more clear: I want to know why pointers are useful over variables when I want to make a clone? Isn't that losing out on the very purpose of pointers ? So I did some reading online and found out that when you create an object using the new keyword, it returns a pointer and stores the object on the heap whereas otherwise it stores it on the stack. So I thought I would lose out on accessing Entities outside of the function where I create it. (Feel free to correct me if I am wrong or educate me. I am here to learn :) )

Comment: There are various reasons to use dynamic allocation, but if you don't really _want_ a dynamic lifetime, then in principle you don't need it. However, if you want runtime polymorphism (as you Component subclasses show), it's hard to do without indirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question here is, what should the class Entity look like ? Should I create separate CopyConstructor, Assignment Constructor and Destructor for this class ? Also if I want to implement copying one Entity into another (deep copying), is it necessary to have all 3 (Copy, Assignment and Destructor) ?

The answer to this doesn't really depend on what the `Entity` *looks like*, but on what semantics it is intended to have.

You say every `Entity` is "unique", but every object in C++ (even every `int`, even when they happen to have the same value) is technically unique. So what do you really mean?

1. Should an `Entity` be copyable? Copy-constructing an `Entity` would mean two `Entity` objects have the same contents (literally if the component pointers are shallow-copied, and logically if they're deep-copied).

   If not, you probably don't want to write a (or may explicitly `delete` the) copy constructor and/or copy-assignment operator.
2. Should an `Entity` be moveable? Probably yes, since it doesn't violate uniqueness and makes them easier to use efficiently.

   If so, you should make sure it has a move constructor and move-assignment operator (either by writing it or arranging for the compiler to generate useful defaults).

> Also if I want to implement copying one Entity into another (deep copying)

That seems to violate your uniqueness constraint, but yes, you'd want a copy constructor and copy-assignment operator for this.

However, best practice is to avoid interleaving resource management with your program logic. So, instead of writing all these, consider having a smart pointer automate it for you. See for comparison the *Rule of Zero* mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172724/212858).

In fact, we can illustrate all the reasonable semantics with very little code:

```
template <typename ComponentPtr>
struct ZeroEntity
{
  Rectangle bound;
  std::vector<ComponentPtr> components;
};

using ShallowCopyZeroEntity = ZeroEntity<std::shared_ptr<Component>>;
using NoCopyOnlyMoveEntity = ZeroEntity<std::unique_ptr<Component>>;
using DeepCopyZeroEntity = ZeroEntity<my::clone_ptr<Component>>;
```

except for the fact that we still need to write a deep-copying `clone_ptr`, something like

```
namespace my {
template <typename T>
class clone_ptr
{
  std::unique_ptr<T> p_;

  std::unique_ptr<T> clone() const { return std::unique_ptr<T>{p_ ? p_->Clone() : nullptr}; }

public:

  using pointer = typename std::unique_ptr<T>::pointer;

  explicit clone_ptr(pointer p) : p_(p) {}

  // copy behaviour is where the cloning happens
  clone_ptr(clone_ptr const& other) : p_(other.clone()) {}
  clone_ptr& operator=(clone_ptr other)
  {
    other.swap(*this);
  }

  // move behaviour (and destructor) generated by unique_ptr
  clone_ptr(clone_ptr&& other) = default;
  clone_ptr& operator=(clone_ptr&&) = default;

  // now write all the same swap, release, reset, operator* etc. as std::unique_ptr
};
}
```

... and if that looks like a lot, imagine how messy it would have been interleaved with your `Entity` code instead of collected into one place like this.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I was just getting used to the very idea of smart pointers so I did not use that in my solution. This project is more of a learning experience for me. I tried implementing the solution without pointers as shown below. I correct myself by saying Entity is unique. I think a better way to say it is they may or may not have multiple components in the vector<Components> and different Rectangles. This doesn't really make them unique because I still need to enable some system of being able to clone them. Please let me know if my solution could lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose is only to enable copying of the Entity. Does this work ?

```
#include "Components.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Entity
{

public:
    Rectangle& Box;
    vector<Component*>& Components;

    //Default constructor call
    Entity(): Box(*new Rectangle), Components(*new vector<Component*>){}
 
    //Constructor call with parameters
    Entity(Rectangle& B, vector<Component*>& C) : Box(B), Components(C){}

    //Copy constructor that makes Entity copyable
    Entity(const Entity& E) : Box(*new Rectangle(E.Box)), Components(*new vector<Component*>(E.Components.size())) {
     
 
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < E.Components.size(); i++) {
            Components[i] = E.Components[i]->Clone();
        }
    }

    //Assignment operator constructor
    Entity& operator=(const Entity& E){ 
        //Entity* pE = &E;
        if (this != &E)
        {
            delete& Box;
            delete& Components;
            Box = *new Rectangle(E.Box);
            Components = *new vector<Component*>(E.Components.size());
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < E.Components.size(); i++) {
                Components[i] = E.Components[i]->Clone();
            }
        }
         return *this;

    }

};
```

Comment: Decide on the semantics of things first. Should the `Components` vector live exactly as long as the Entity? Then make it a regular member. You don't need to dynamically allocate a single vector.

Comment: If you _do_ have to dynamically allocate something, don't store just a `&` reference. They're not used to indicate ownership, and a raw pointer at least doesn't hide the code smell. Prefer automatic lifetime first, and if you must dynamically allocate, use smart pointers. Owning raw pointers (which you must manually `delete`) are a distant third choice, and owning references don't appear on the list at all.

Comment: The cloning itself will work (if inelegantly), but your `operator=` has zero exception safety: if either `new` or one of the `Clone` calls throws an exception, you've already trashed the left-hand-side `Entity` you were assigning to, and now it can't be used. First write a destructor, then write a non-throwing `swap`  (or move assignment), and write the normal copy assignment that copy-constructs a temporary and then swaps it with `*this`.

Comment: Thanks. That makes so much more sense !